# Procedural Sphere Texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, geometry, textures

I am currently following the procedural tutorial on creating procedural spheres found [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/procedural-spheres-in-opengl-es.html) and I am trying to merge it with the textures tutorial with it to create a 3d version of Earth found [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html).

So far, I was able to successfully bind the texture on the sphere. However, I am having some problems with the way it was displayed. I have attached links to the screen captures to further show the result. As you can see, the image is repeated and is not entirely wrapped on the sphere.

[image]
[image]

I am using this code, which I am guessing might cause the problem:

```
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sphereTriangleStripVertices);
```

I hope you can help me with this as I have been trying to fix this for weeks now.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have "glTexCoordPointer(2 ..." instead of "glTexCoordPointer(3..." as you must almost certainly have two values for each coordinate.